# Minimize $3\sqrt{5-2x}+\sqrt{13-6y}$ subject to $x^2+y^2=4$

Tags: optimization, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, circles, maxima-minima

> If $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2+y^2=4$, find the minimum value of $3\sqrt{5-2x}+\sqrt{13-6y}$.

I could observe that we can write
$$3\sqrt{5-2x}+\sqrt{13-6y}=3\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1-2x}+\sqrt{x^2+y^2+9-6y}$$
$\implies$
$$3\sqrt{5-2x}+\sqrt{13-6y}=3\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{x^2+(y-3)^2}=3PA+PB$$
Where $P$ is a generic point on $x^2+y^2=4$ and $A(1,0),B(0,3)$.
So the problem essentially means which point on the circle $x^2+y^2=4$ minimizes $3PA+PB$.
I am really struggling to find the geometrical notion of this and hence unable to solve.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

Comment: Why not let $(x,y) =2(\cos t, \sin t)$ and use calculus?

Comment: see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimize+3sqrt%285-2x%29%2Bsqrt%2813-6y%29%2Cx%5E2%2By%5E2%3D4

Comment: $P$ is the intersection between $x^2+y^2=4$ and the circle with diameter $AB$. This aligns with what sirous has said (there is another value on the other side of the circle), and $3PA + PB$ for this choice of $P$ is exactly $2 \sqrt{10}$.

Comment: I think there is something to take with derivative see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+%283sqrt%285-2x%29%2Bsqrt%2813-6sqrt%284-x%C2%B2%29%29%29%3D0  and the function is convex on his domain .

Answer (score 2):

Comment: you may use this modification:

We rewrite final relation as:

$$A=\sqrt{[3(x-1)=a]^2+(3y=b)^2}+\sqrt{(x=a')^2+(y-3=b')^2}$$

and use this inequality:

$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{a'^2+b'^2}\geq\sqrt{(a+a')^2+(b+b'^2)}$

we get:

$A\geq\sqrt{16(x^2+y^2)-24(x+y)+18}$

$x^2+y^2=4$

$\Rightarrow$

$A\geq \sqrt{82-24(x+y)}$

If $x=y=\sqrt 2$ then $A\geq\sqrt{84-67.7}\approx 4$

Update:Wolfram says minimum is $2\sqrt {10}=6.32$ at $(x,y)=(\frac25+\frac{3\sqrt6}5=1.87, \frac 65-\frac{\sqrt6}5)=0.71$. If we put this in $\sqrt{82-24(x+y)}$ we get 4.47. mind you x and y must suffice $x^2+y^2=4$, and what Wolfram gives does; $1.87^2+0.71^2=4$.Hence 40 can not be minimum .

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimize+3sqrt%285-2x%29%2Bsqrt%2813-6y%29%2Cx%5E2%2By%5E2%3D4 commented by albus the min value is $\sqrt{40}$

Comment: But wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+3√%285-2x%29%2B√%2813-6y%29%2C+if+x%5E2%2B, gives $2\sqrt {10}\approx 6.32$. I typed: minimize $A =3\sqrt{3-5x}+\sqrt{13-6y}, If $ x^2+y^2=4$. You can try.

Comment: In your edit,you wrote $x$ and $y$ must suffice $x^2$+$y^2$=5 but they should satisfy $x^2+y^2=4$ once check the edit

Comment: @Learner, just a typo, sorry about it.

Answer (score 2):

We can parametrize the constraint condition as $$(x,y) = (2 \cos t, 2 \sin t), \quad t \in [0,2\pi),$$ hence we are interested in the extrema of $$f(t) = 3\sqrt{5-4\cos t} + \sqrt{13-12\sin t}.$$  Differentiating to locate critical points, we find $$\sin t \sqrt{13 - 12 \sin t} = \cos t \sqrt{5 - 4 \cos t},$$ or $$\tan^2 t = \frac{5 \sec t - 4}{13 \sec t - 12 \tan t}.$$  Collecting like terms yields $$(12 \tan^3 t - 4)^2 = (13 \tan^2 t - 5)^2 \sec^2 t,$$ hence with $z = \tan t$,
$$\begin{align}
0 &= (13 \tan^2 t - 5)^2 (1 + \tan^2 t) - (12 \tan^3 t - 4)^2 \\
&= 25 z^6 + 39 z^4 + 96 z^3 - 105 z^2 + 9 \\
&= (5z^2 + 6z - 3)(5z^4 - 6z^3 + 18z^2 - 6z - 3).
\end{align}$$
Consequently, the critical values correspond to$$\tan t = z = \frac{-3 \pm 2 \sqrt{6}}{5}.$$  The roots of the quartic factor are all complex-valued.  It follows that $$(\cos t, \sin t) = \left\{ \left( \frac{3 \sqrt{6} - 2}{10}, \frac{3 \sqrt{6} + 2}{10} \right), \left( - \frac{6 + \sqrt{6}}{10}, \frac{6 - \sqrt{6}}{10} \right) \right\},$$ and $$f(t) = \left\{ \frac{\sqrt{101 + 6 \sqrt{6}} + 9 \sqrt{3} - 3 \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{5}}, 2 \sqrt{10} \right\}.$$  The first one is the maximum and the second is the minimum.  Attached is a plot of $f$:

[image]

Comment: How did you spot the factors of $25z^6+39z^4+96z^3−105z^2+9$?

Answer (score 2):

Nice problem! Here is a solution using geometry.

For the moment, lets forget $P$ is lying on the circle $x^2+y^2=4$. Call the origin $O=(0,0)$. $A=(1,0), B=(0,3)$. So $OA=1, OB=3$ and $\angle BOA = 90^\circ$. Draw the quadrilateral $OAPB$.

[image]

Note that we have to minimize
$$3\cdot PA+1\cdot PB=OB\cdot PA + OA\cdot PB$$

We know from [Ptolemy's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_inequality) that
$$OB\cdot PA + OA\cdot PB \ge AB \cdot OP$$

with equality only when $O,A,P,B$ lie on a circle.

Thus the desired minimum is attained when $P$ is the intersection of circle with diameter $AB$, call it $S_2$ and $S_1:x^2+y^2=4$.

The value of this minimum is $AB\cdot OP $. Since $AB=\sqrt{10}$ and $OP$ is radius of $S_1$, this minimum value is $2\sqrt{10}$.

---

Though coordinates of $P$ are not needed, they can be quickly found as intersection of common chord of the two circles and the circle $S_1$. Equation for common chord is $x+3y=4$ hence ordinate of $P$ satisfies $5y^2-12y+6=0$ whose only geometrically valid solution is
$$y_P=\frac{6-\sqrt{6}}{5} \Rightarrow x_P=\frac{2+3\sqrt{6}}{5}$$

which matches other answers and WA.

Answer (score 1):

Making

$$
\cases{
u^2 = 5-2x\\
v^2 = 13-6y
}
$$

we have equivalently

$$
\min_{u,v} 3u+v\ \ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \ \frac{1}{4} \left(5-u^2\right)^2+\frac{1}{36} \left(13-v^2\right)^2=4
$$

now, as the objective function is linear, and the orbits defined by $\frac 14\left(5-u^2\right)^2+\frac{1}{36} \left(13-v^2\right)^2=4$ are regular and closed, the solution should be equivalent to:

find $\lambda$ such that $3u+v = \lambda$ is tangent to $g(u,v)=\left(5-u^2\right)^2+\frac{1}{36} \left(13-v^2\right)^2=4$. To accomplish that, after substituting $v = \lambda-3u$ into $g(u,v)$ we obtain a polynomial

$$
p(v,\lambda) = \frac{\lambda ^4}{90}-\frac{2 \lambda ^3 u}{15}+\frac{3 \lambda ^2 u^2}{5}-\frac{13 \lambda ^2}{45}-\frac{6 \lambda  u^3}{5}+\frac{26 \lambda 
   u}{15}+u^4-\frac{18 u^2}{5}+\frac{25}{9}
$$

At tangency, this polynomial should have a double real root or

$$
p(v,\lambda) = (v-r_1(\lambda))^2(v^2+c_1(\lambda)v+c_2(\lambda)))
$$

and identifying coefficients we have

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 -c_2 r_1^2+\frac{\lambda ^4}{90}-\frac{13 \lambda ^2}{45}+\frac{25}{9} & = & 0\\
 -c_1 r_1^2+2 c_2 r_1-\frac{2 \lambda ^3}{15}+\frac{26 \lambda }{15} & = & 0\\
 2 c_1 r_1-c_2+\frac{3 \lambda ^2}{5}-r_1^2-\frac{18}{5} & = & 0\\
 -c_1-\frac{6 \lambda }{5}+2 r_1 & = & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

solving now for $r_1,c_1,c_2,\lambda$ we obtain the feasible results

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
r_1 & c_1 & c_2 & \lambda\\
 3 \sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}-\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} & \frac{1}{5} \left(10 \left(3 \sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}-\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}\right)-12 \sqrt{10}\right) &
   \frac{27480384-2892672 \sqrt{10} \left(3 \sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}-\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}\right)}{2410560} & 2 \sqrt{10} \\
 3 \sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}+\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} & \frac{1}{5} \left(10 \left(3 \sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}+\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}\right)-12 \sqrt{10}\right) &
   \frac{27480384-2892672 \sqrt{10} \left(3 \sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}+\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}\right)}{2410560} & 2 \sqrt{10} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

so the minimum is at $\lambda = 2\sqrt{10}$